# Cumulative SUM in a query (SQL access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, cumulative-sum

Using MS access SQL I have a query (actually a UNION made of multiple queries) and need a cumulative sum (actually a statement of account which items are in chronological order).

How do I get a cumulative sum?

Since they are duplicates by date I have to add a new ID, however, SQL in MS access does not seem to have ROW_ID or similar.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output as formatted text.

Comment: Its ugly and it relies on the SORT but you can try following along w/ this link I found. https://theaccessbuddy.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/using-ms-access-to-create-a-running-total-or-a-cumulative-sum-part-1-of-2/

Comment: Build an Access report and use textbox RunningSum property. Data should be provided within question as text table, not image. Try copy/paste of Access table into question or use a tables generator like: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Thank you @Josh but this common solution produces a new table filled by the query, ie. update issues to be expected. 
How are professionals dealing with it?
Sure I could even create a new recordset in VBA and calculating the SUMs but I don't think this is the way to do ..?

Comment: Another reference to review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/create-a-running-totals-query. Did you consider suggestion for building report?

Comment: Please find sample data, one Table with donations given from states the other from individuals. We require to have both data merged, sorted by date and cumulative sum shown. See the output, whenever there are donations from same date (in this example 18.3. and 22.11) the cumulative sum fails!
We need a ROW NUMBER variable to create the cumulative sum .. not seeing this on access SQL
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu6ds084gez8bpd/RollingSumExmpl.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Most here will not download files. All info needed to analyze issue should be within the question and that means data as text tables. Might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db there. Use UNION query to 'merge' tables and build report.

Answer (score 0):

So, we need to sort donation data into chronological order across multiple tables with duplicates.  First combine all the tables of donators in one query which sets up the simplest syntax. Then to put things in order we need **to have an order for the duplicate dates**.  The dataset has two natural ways to sort duplicate dates including the donator and the amount.  For instance, we could decide that after the date bigger donations come first, If the rule is complicated enough we abstract it to a code module and into public function and include it in the query so that we can sort by it:

```
'Sorted Donations:'

SELECT  (BestDonator(q.donator)) as BestDonator, *
FROM tblCountries as q
UNION SELECT  (BestDonator(j.donator)) as BestDonator, *
FROM tblIndividuals as j
ORDER BY EvDate Asc, Amount DESC , BestDonator DESC;

Public Function BestDonator(donator As String) As Long
BestDonator = Len(donator) 'longer names are better :)'
End Function
```

with sorted donations we have settled on an order for the duplicate dates and have combined both individual donations and country donations, so now we can calculate the running sum directly using either dsum or a subquery.  There is no need to calculate row id.  The tricky part is getting the syntax correct.  I ended up abstracting the running sum calculation to a function and omitting BestDonator because I couldn't easily paste together this query in the query designer and I ran out of time to bug fix

[image]

```
Public Function RunningSum(EvDate As Date, Amount As Currency)
RunningSum = DSum("Amount", "Sorted Donations", "(EvDate < #" & [EvDate] & "#) OR (EvDate = #" & [EvDate] & "# AND Amount >= " & [Amount] & ")")
End Function
```

Carefully note the OR in the Dsum part of the RunningSum calculation.  This is the tricky part to summing the right amounts.

```
'output

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      donator       |       EvDate       |       Amount       |     RunningSum     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Reiny              |          1/10/2020 |                321 | 321                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Czechia            |           3/1/2020 |               7455 | 7776               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Germany            |          3/18/2020 |               4222 | 11998              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Jim                |          3/18/2020 |                222 | 12220              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Australien         |          4/15/2020 |              13423 | 25643              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mike               |          5/31/2020 |                345 | 25988              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Portugal           |           6/6/2020 |               8755 | 34743              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Slovakia           |          8/31/2020 |               3455 | 38198              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Steve              |           9/6/2020 |                875 | 39073              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Japan              |         10/10/2020 |               5234 | 44307              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| John               |         10/11/2020 |                465 | 44772              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Slowenia           |         11/11/2020 |               4665 | 49437              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Spain              |         11/22/2020 |               7677 | 57114              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Austria            |         11/22/2020 |               3221 | 60335              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bill               |         11/22/2020 |                767 | 61102              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bert               |          12/1/2020 |                755 | 61857              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hungaria           |         12/24/2020 |               9996 | 71853              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```